# Reuse an UITableViewCell (customized height for each one) in a twitter-like client

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I am working on a project like twitter client iOS version. When designing the tableview, every cell changes the height to accommodate its content (tweet).

But I met a problem: the current screen's cell height works well, but when scroll down, the new cell  reuses the height of old cells.

Comment: Are you setting the height of your cells in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` based on the content that must appear in the cell?

Comment: @jonkroll  yes,i have already done that. im wondering that the resue cell 's height is changeable?

Comment: Moonlight is right. It doesn't matter what the reuse cell's height is. You want to use the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. If it's not changing the height, then you've done something wrong. Share some code if you want better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, table programming is where model-view-controller approach really comes usefull. If you change your cell height somewhere like `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` you could get a feeling that it works - but it doesn't. What you can do in this method is modify your data and reload the table (or part of it).

As mentioned in comments above you'll have to:

Provide correct height for each cell in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Provide correct view (cell) in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Whenewer you want to make some change you should modify your data in `model` (or appropriate object holding your content-related data) and then call one of the `UITableView's reload` methods, possibly:

```
- (void)reloadData
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Apple's documentation can be scarce (though i think it's quite proffesional):
These would be the basic links for you:

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)